# Purpose of webhooks in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, shared-libraries, webhooks, sonar-runner

I came across Webhooks in SonarQube. I referred a document https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Webhooks. But I didn't get for what webhooks can be used for SonarQube. As mentioned in the document I didn't seen webhooks in Administration > Configuration > General Settings > Webhooks. Do I need to add any plugin for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webhooks come out of the box starting with SonarQube version 6.2. Their purpose is to alert 3rd-party systems that the asynchronous processing of an analysis report is complete.

Anticipated uses are:

- notifying your CI job or pipeline that the quality gate status has been computed
- posting fresh analysis results to a wallboard
- ...

Comment: Thank you @G.Ann. But when I see Configuration > General Settings > Webhooks I didn't seen any webhook option over there. is any thing that I need to do manually to get it

Comment: What version of SonarQube are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.6.6 version

Comment: Then webhooks don't exist for you yet. They were added in 6.2

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want your raspberry pi to release a packet of **gummy bears**, everytime a quality gate is green - how would you do that?

Option A: You might either let your raspberry pi *poll* the quality gate status. But this causes a lot of network traffic and will cause slight delays.

Option B: You configure a webhook in SonarQube, and let your raspberry pi be a HTTP server.

- Less network traffic
- You receive your gummy bears without delay
- Probably easier to implement!